# Translating EBNF into Irony

Tags: c#, ebnf, irony

I am using Irony to create a parser for a scripting language, but I've come across a little problem: how do I translate an EBNF expression like this in Irony?

```
'(' [ Ident { ',' Ident } ] ')'
```

I already tried some tricks like

```
Chunk.Rule = (Ident | Ident + "," + Chunk);
CallArgs.Rule = '(' + Chunk + ')' | '(' + ')';
```

But it's ugly and I'm not even sure if that works the way it should (haven't tried it yet...). Has anyone any suggestions?

EDIT:
I found out these helper methods (MakeStarList, MakePlusList) but couldn't find out how to use them, because of the complete lack of documentation of Irony... Has anyone any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Declare the non-terminals
var Ident = new NonTerminal("Ident");
var IdentList = new NonTerminal("Term");

// Rules
IdentList.Rule = ToTerm("(") + MakePlusRule(IdentList, ",", Ident) + ")";
Ident.Rule = // specify whatever Ident is (I assume you mean an identifier of some kind).
```

You can use the MakePlusRule helper method to define a one-or-many occurrence of some terminal. The MakePlusRule is basically just present your terminals as standard recursive list-idiom:

```
Ident |  IdentList + "," + Ident
```

It also marks the terminal as representing a list, which will tell the parser to unfold the list-tree as a convenient list of child nodes.